# jq concatenation with special characters

Tags: json, string, concatenation, escaping, jq

I am trying to append some Grafana dashboard query things to existing queries. The Select works and doing a simple =+ "TEST" added successfully.

The actual append I have has {} * and ""

```
") * on(instance, process_id) group_left(name, display_name, run_as) windows_service_info\{display_name=~"$variable",job="$job"\})
```

so the jq is

```
 jq '. | (.dashboard.panels[].targets[].expr | select(contains("sum((rate(wmi"))) += ") * on(instance, process_id) group_left(name, display_name, run_as) windows_service_info\{display_name=~"$variable",job="$job"\})"'
```

I tried the string literal

```
@text {"text":") * on(instance, process_id) group_left(name, display_name, run_as) windows_service_info\{display_name=~"$variable",job="$job"\})"}'
```

getting errors like:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Comment: Escape the quote character:`jq -rn '"... { \" * } ..."'` will produce `... { " * } ...`

Answer (score 0):

As json.org says, `"any codepoint except " or \ or control characters"` can be included within a JSON string without being escaped.

In the question, the given string does contain both `"` and `\`, so to convert that string to a valid JSON string, both would need to be escaped.

Comment: Note that I believe it's only referring to the 32 control characters in the ASCII range. (Other sources confirm this.) The other 33 do not need escaping. (No harm in doing so, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotation marks inside a quoted string. And the initial `.|` is redundant:

```
jq '(.dashboard.panels[].targets[].expr | select(contains("sum((rate(wmi"))) += ") * on(instance, process_id) group_left(name, display_name, run_as) windows_service_info{display_name=~\"$variable\",job=\"$job\"})"'
```

`\{` and `\}` must not be escaped. Unless you require a literal `\{` in your output, then your JQ string must contain `\\{` and `\\}`.